# Parsing scala case classes with Jackson

Tags: json, scala, jackson, jackson-module-scala

My understanding was that jackson's `DefaultScalaModule` is supposed to be able to read scala case classes out-of-the-box. But it seems to choke as long as I give it more than one field:

```
 val mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
 scala> mapper.readValue("""{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}""", classOf[Map[String, String]])
 res98: Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> bar, bar -> foo)

 class Foo(foo: String) 
 scala> mapper.readValue("""{"foo": "bar"}""", classOf[Foo])
 res101: Foo = Foo(bar)

 class Foo(foo: String, bar: String) 
 scala> mapper.readValue("""{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}""", classOf[Foo])
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'foo' (in class Foo)
 at [Source: {"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Strange. Working for me as you've written (with the class Foo declared as a **case class**.) Which versions of the libraries are you using?

Comment: @Mikesname yeah, it was actually a `case class` when I was trying it, somehow, lost the `case` when I pasted it into the question. I am using Jackson 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been using Jackson 2.5.4. Looks like upgrading to 2.6.6 fixes it.

I tried upgrading to 2.7.3 at first, and it fixes that too, but seems to break something else (not sure what exactly, some of my tests failed, but I haven't figured out the exact cause, and just dropped it, since 2.6.6 seems to do what I need).